# aiogram, fetch all from database and message in telegram bot by 5 rows with labeks

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram, fetchall

Good day,Everyone

I am trying to build a telegram bot that fetchs all rows from database and shows message by 5 rows in tg bot with next page inline_keybord

here is my **code**

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import mysql.connector as connector
from config import TOKEN_API

bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

conn = connector.connect(
    database = 'awesugn_products',
    host = 'localhost',
    username = 'root',
    password = 'root'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def construct_keyboard(data: tuple, page: int) -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    length=len(data)
    kb={'inline_keyboard': []}
    buttons=[]
    if page > 1: #preventing going to -1 page
        buttons.append({'text':'<-', 'callback_data':f'page_{page-1}'})
    #adding a neat page number
    buttons.append({'text':f'{page}/{length}', 'callback_data':'none'})
    if page < length: #preventing going out of range
        buttons.append({'text':'->', 'callback_data':f'page_{page+1}'})
    kb['inline_keyboard'].append(buttons)
    return kb

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start (message: types.Message):
    cursor.execute("SELECT product_name, discount_price, regualar_price FROM discount_products")
    objs = cursor.fetchall()
    json_data = []
    for obj in objs:
        json_data.append({
            "product_name" : obj[0],
            "discount_price" : obj[1],
            "regualar_price" : obj[2]
            })
    await message.answer(json_data[0], reply_markup=construct_keyboard(objs, 1))

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='page_')
async def page(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    page=int(call.data.split('_')[1])
    cursor.execute("SELECT product_name, discount_price, regualar_price FROM discount_products")
    objs = cursor.fetchall()
    json_data = []
    for obj in objs:
        json_data.append({
            "product_name" : obj[0],
            "discount_price" : obj[1],
            "regualar_price" : obj[2]
            })
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, json_data[page - 1], reply_markup=construct_keyboard(objs, page))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

my code is working like this in tg bot

[image: result]

I want see the result in beautiful content with bold labels and display by 5 rows on each page on telegram bot.

for example:

```
**product_name**: banana 240 kg
**discount_price**: 21990
**regualar_price**: 31990

**product_name**: biscuit 10 kg 
**discount_price**: 21990
**regualar_price**: 31990
```

in this example I showed by 2 rows in message,
how to display message like this with 5 rows in each message and with next page inline_keyboard where there bulk of rows are fetched from database?

Comment: Could you clarify, do you need to see multiple products on the same page?

Comment: hi biflé, 
yes I would like to see by 5 products on each page with bold formating